# Looking for a light-weight spring 3.x based CMS/Blog Engine

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, blogs

I would like to maintain a blog which is running on Java, preferably light-weight. Since I work with Spring a lot I thought it would be nice to have a Spring 3.x based CMS/Blog-engine (instead of rolling my own).

I would appreciate your input. I can go for niche projects as long as they have a good basic structure and hopefully contribute back

Answer (score 2):

Found few CMS based on Spring

[Magnolia](http://www.magnolia-cms.com/), [Walrus](http://walrus.lt/), [Dotcms](http://dotcms.com/)

For Spring 3.x, go  with Magnolia CMS. You can quickly get an idea about this [here](http://www.developer.com/java/web/spring-framework-and-magnolia-cms-creating-complex-java-based-websites.html).

Answer (score 0):

dotCMS has Spring 3.x support and OSGI based Spring support which allows you to deploy and undeploy your spring webapps on the fly, without a server restart.  See:

http://dotcms.com/docs/latest/DynamicPluginsSpring